# Alter statement swaps foreign key name and index name in MySQL 5.6.40

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have an alter statement as follows :

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT fk_randomName 
  FOREIGN KEY fx_randomName (col1, col2) 
  REFERENCES TestParent (parent_col1, parent_col2) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

Running this yields a table with the constraint name as "fx_randomName" and the index name as "fk_randomName". The foreign key constraint name and index name are getting swapped for some reason.

I've read through MySQL docs and it looks like MySQL supposedly ignores index names if given in the alter statement

> For ALTER TABLE, unlike CREATE TABLE, ADD FOREIGN KEY ignores index_name if given and uses an automatically generated foreign key name. As a workaround, include the CONSTRAINT clause to specify the foreign key name:

> ADD CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY (....) ...

So then how come our tables (on MySQL versions 5.6.40 & 5.6.41) are getting these swapped names? We are running innodb engine.

Also, when I do not specify the index name, both the FK and index created get the same name, the name specified after the CONSTRAINT keyword as mentioned in the docs.

I've looked at the change logs for minor versions 5.6.30 and up to see if this was fixed in some version, but wasn't able to find anything relevant. Maybe I missed it or its on a bug list somewhere, any pointers or direction would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: I tested your ALTER TABLE on MySQL 5.7.27 and both the index and the constraint were named `fk_randomName`. I suggest you upgrade, because MySQL 5.6 will be end-of-life in two months anyway (2021-02-05). https://lefred.be/content/mysql-5-6-eol-is-february-2021/

Comment: Thank you for the format edit and for trying it in 5.7. Unfortunately upgrading our Prod instance will not be a an easy feat and I am mostly trying to understand this behaviour, whether someone else has seen this happen (& remembers it LOL) or if it is on a known bugs list somewhere.

Comment: The closest thing I found was https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44053 which seems to be the bug report that resulted in the documentation change you excerpted above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this bug link! I've searched for bugs under the alter statement and constraint keyword but could not find anything relevant.